# urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection ...>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Why does one see this error in Selenium;

`urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0xsome_hex_address>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused`

When using various functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please ensure you have not somewhere terminated your session. For example (in Python);

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver',options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.somewebsite.com')
try:
  WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@type='file']")))
finally:
  driver.quit()
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS,"someclass")))
```

The second `WebDriverWait` will fail with the said error message because the "finally" clause of the "try" is always executed, and thus the driver quit/was closed. Hence, the subsequent `WebDriverWait` failed. Easy to miss.

By the way, in the above example you could change the "finally:" to "except:" to 'only' do a `driver.quit()` if the try fails.