# HTTPSConnectionPool with extra /

Tags: robotframework, urllib3

The code I use in Eclipse , file.robot  is

```
${resp}=    Get Request    localhost    http://localhost:8080/UI/core/other/htmlreport/    params=apikey=${API_KEY}
```

at that point there is no extra  /  character

but the response is with an extra  /

```
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /http://localhost:8080/UI/core/other/htmlreport/?apikey=d9i7qom4p7m12rd2eqf2612s95 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000021C6BD54D90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Kan geen verbinding maken omdat de doelcomputer de verbinding actief heeft geweigerd'))
```

zoom in:
/http://
Where does that extra character  /  come from?

---

it is something with the session,

but this causes an error in the next step as well:

KEYWORD  RequestsLibrary . Create Session localhost, http://localhost:8080/UI/core/other/htmlreport/, params=apikey=${API_KEY}

```
Documentation:

Create Session: create a HTTP session to a server
 

Start / End / Elapsed:
20201104 14:55:45.917 / 20201104 14:55:45.930 / 00:00:00.013 

14:55:45.918 INFO Creating Session using : alias=localhost, url=http://localhost:8080/UI/core/other/htmlreport/, headers=params=apikey=d9i7qom4p7m12rd2eqf2612s95,                     cookies={}, auth=None, timeout=None, proxies=None, verify=False,                     debug=0  
 

14:55:45.929 FAIL ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Comment: The cause is something with the session? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56424704/urllib3-exceptions-newconnectionerror-urllib3-connection-httpconnection

Answer (score 1):

The docs aren't completely clear, but it's exepected that your create a session first and then use that session to call `Get Request`

```
    Create Session    localhost      http://localhost:8080
    ${resp}=          Get request    localhost    /UI/core/other/htmlreport/
```

You can see in the code that it expects the session to have a schema and host, while the `uri` parameter is the path - https://github.com/MarketSquare/robotframework-requests/blob/c1e63fdc2738b1f95cbfd9968911261b7c8829ae/src/RequestsLibrary/RequestsKeywords.py#L990

Comment: Thanks at least now I know where the slash comes from...